# Why does Type.Name property of Generics end with apostrophe and a number?

Tags: c#, generics, types

Suppose I want to know value of `.Name`property for an arbitrary type. Now in most cases I get pretty self explanatory results. "Boolean", "Int32" and such.

But if I try the same thing with Generics, like in this method:

```
static void Test()
    {           
        Type type = typeof(HashSet<int>);
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
        type = typeof(HashSet<string>);
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
        type = typeof(HashSet<bool>);
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name);

        type = typeof(Nullable<int>);
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
        type = typeof(Nullable<float>);
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
        type = typeof(Nullable<bool>);
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name);

    }
```

I get this:

```
HashSet`1
HashSet`1
HashSet`1
Nullable`1
Nullable`1
Nullable`1
```

Is there a special reason why generics have `.Name`s like this? Does the number depend on anything or is it arbitrary? Is it merely feature of my IDE or platform (VS2017/Win10)?

Comment: The number indicates the number of generic parameters. Why is it important to you?

Comment: The number is not random, it is the number of the generic parameters. For example, `typeof(Tuple<int, string>).Name` returns "Tuple`2"

Answer (score 1):

These names are mainly used to differentiate different types.

As you may know, `GenericType<T>` and `GenericType<T, U>` are considered two completely different types, even though they have the same name. If the number of generic parameters of two types are different, then the two types are considered completely different.

To different between different number of generic parameters, the number is used.

For example, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`'s name is "Dictionary`2".

The ` character is used to again differentiate between `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`  and a type that's actually called `Dictionary2`. "`" is an invalid character for an identifier in C#, so this guarantees that there are no types with the same name.

Here is a detailed description of wha the symbols in type names mean: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx